# Trying to build the Evernote SDK for the mac always causes an error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, clang, evernote

I'm trying to build the [Evernote SDK for the mac](https://github.com/holtwick/evernote-sdk-ios) but for some reason Xcode always fails with this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/mauricio/projects/objective-c/evernote-sdk-ios/evernote-sdk-ios/EvernoteSDK-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

It's adding the project folder name twice (see **/evernote-sdk-ios/evernote-sdk-ios/EvernoteSDK-Prefix.pch**) and I can't find anywhere a place where this is being set like this or how I can fix it.

I'm using Xcode 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

And the support team originally pointed me out to the wrong repo, they have now created a separate repo for the Mac version which is [here](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-mac).